How to create uninitialized Vec
I've written some code that reads a binary file into a Vec. I did it using Vec::with_capacity() and unsafe { ...set_len(); }. It works, but clippy complains and the official docs claim that reading into an unintialized vec is undefined behavior. Since the compiler lets it happen, I suspect it's not really that undefined, and I can just shut up clippy with an #[allow(...)], but I'd like to do it "right" if I can. There's lots of examples of using MaybeUninit<> with variables and arrays, but not with Vec, and many of the examples jump through ridiculous hoops for what is a really simple thing. This is a big Vec, so initializing it is a totally unacceptable cost. So what's the "no cost abstraction" way of doing this?
lazy_static! {
/// Map from perfect hash to equivalence class
pub static ref OJP_HIGH_MP5_TABLE_1: Vec<u16> = {
    let mut path: PathBuf = cargo_home().unwrap();
    path.push("onejoker");
    path.push("ojp_high_mp5_table_1.bin.gz");

    let file = fs::File::open(&path).unwrap();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut decoder = GzDecoder::new(&mut reader);

    let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity((MP5_SIZE + 1) * 2);
    #[allow(clippy::uninit_vec)]
    unsafe { bytes.set_len((MP5_SIZE + 1) * 2) };
    let mut buf: [MaybeUninit<u8>; IO_BUF_SIZE] =
    unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };
    let mut start: usize = 0;

    loop {
        let n = decoder.read(
            unsafe { &mut *(buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut [u8; IO_BUF_SIZE]) }
        ).unwrap();
        if n == 0 {
            break;
        }
        bytes[start..start + n].copy_from_slice(
            unsafe { &*(buf.as_ptr() as *const [u8; IO_BUF_SIZE]) }[..n].as_ref()
        );
        start += n;
    }
    assert_eq!(start, (MP5_SIZE + 1) * 2);

    let len = bytes.len() / 2;
    let capacity = bytes.capacity() / 2;
    let ptr = bytes.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u16;
    std::mem::forget(bytes);    // prevents deallocation of the vec

    unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, capacity) }
};

}

Any reason why std::fs::read is not acceptable?

"many of the examples jump through ridiculous hoops for what is a really simple thing" - handling uninitialized memory does seem like an simple thing until you understand that it isn't

“Since the compiler lets it happen, I suspect it's not really that undefined” You used an unsafe block, explicitly opting out of compiler protection from undefined behavior. (And when people talk about undefined behavior, it’s effectively always in reference to things that a compiler lets happen.)

@kmdreko Yes, because the file on disk is compressed and I'm decompressing it into the larger buffer. Also, the Vec is a lazy_static and this all happens in the static initializer.

If you're using with_capacity, you can probably do what you want with .take(n).read_to_end(&mut vec). But you'll need to share code if you want this question to survive.

Fair enough. I couldn't simplify the code down much without making it unrunnable.

@kmdreko "Allocate some memory; don't initialize it; write some stuff to it" is a very conceptually simple thing to do that I've been doing in various languages for almost 50 years. Rust making hard to wrong is a good feature; Rust making it hard to do right is not.

There's a function that decompresses a whole file into a string. I might be able to use that if I can create a Vec that uses that string memory.

Just make both buf and bytes normal initially-empty Vecs? Having the backing memory be preallocated and uninitialized without you having to worry about it is exactly what the whole Vec type (/Vec::with_capacity) is for.

@LeeDanielCrocker It's not exactly clear why pushing bytes onto a Vec doesn't work for this use case. This seems like a case of over-complicating what is actually a simple thing.

@cdhowie This table decompresses into 133MB of memory. Initializing that memory only for it to be overwritten is a termendous waste of time.

@cafce25 A static array would work too, if it weren't for a compiler (LLVM?) bug that tries to copy static arrays onto the stack when compiling without optimization. Needless to say, 133MB crashes the stack.

@LeeDanielCrocker What makes you think pushing bytes onto a Vec will double-initialize it?

(Vec continues to be the right way to do it, but note that you can put an array in a Box to keep it off the stack.)

@Ry- (You can but you have to do that via Vec or the array will get created on the stack and then moved to the heap.)

@cdhowie Good question. Maybe I should just use something like "extend from slice" and see if the compiler optimizes away all the abstractions of that (like cloning each byte).

@LeeDanielCrocker That's where I'd start. In fact I'm not sure there's another solution that avoids UB since I/O traits can't read into a &mut [MaybeUninit<u8>]. If they could, then you could still do this mostly using just stuff Vec provides (spare_capacity_mut + set_len).

@LeeDanielCrocker This question may be of interest to you in this regard.

@Ry- I agree that Vec is designed for hiding the details of memory allocation, and it does a great job. On the disk side of things where I'm using an array as an I/O buffer, all is well--I end up with system calls to read() that are passed the address of the uninitialized buffer and no effort is wasted. I just want to clean up the bit where those bytes are copied into their final resting place of the new Vec with the equivalent of and old-fashioned memcpy().

@LeeDanielCrocker I get the desire to do that, but keep in mind that disk access is going to be orders of magnitude slower than copying bytes around in memory. If you profile this I'm sure you'll see way more time being spent waiting for the read to complete than shuffling bytes around.

Read::read_to_end seems to be exactly what you want to do here‽ No need for an uninitialized Vec.

@cdhowie Thanks for the pointer to the other question (though it seems more relevant to the array case rather than Vec). And yes, disk I/O might overwhelm the buffer initialization, and I should probably measure the time to initialize the 133MB buffer. It just rankles my old-school C hacker nerves to knowingly waste cycles.

@cafce25 As I mentioned, GzDecoder has read_to_string() that sucks up the whole thing, and I might then be able to convert that memory into my Vec.

@LeeDanielCrocker: No effort is wasted compared to the code in the question if you use Vec in a natural way – it’s exactly the same memory access pattern. You can do better by not using an intermediate buffer, which is what read_to_end accomplishes. I think you’re missing that GzDecoder implements Read.

@LeeDanielCrocker That method comes from the same trait that read_to_end comes from. It's important to note that read_to_string will fail if the contents are not a valid UTF-8 string from start to end. If you're dealing with binary data, you want to avoid strings completely.

@LeeDanielCrocker what GzDecoder are you using? The one I am looking at does implement Read and thus literally has read_to_end available.

@cafce25 Yes, GzDecoder has read_to_end(), so then I just have to convert the Vec into a Vec, which I'm already doing. Sound like that might be the way to go.

As for reinterpreting Vec<u8> as Vec<u16>, see How best to convert &[u8] to &[u16]. In this case, since it’s a lazy_static and doesn’t look intended to be modified, you might want to leak it so the overall type is &'static [u16], to deal with the issue mentioned in the thread about deallocation (although nothing lazy_static is ever actually dropped so it’s probably fine…?).

I could do a really ugly hack by creating the initial Vec, check the raw address and add one if it's not aligned, leaking one byte.

@LeeDanielCrocker Yep as long as you build a slice from the pointer, that would be fine. Trying to reform a Vec from that modified pointer would be UB.

As mentioned in the comments by cdhowie and cafce25, you’re mainly doing a Read::read_to_end. Your loop gets the same result as this safe Rust, but the safe Rust actually copies less (there’s no intermediate buf):
let file = fs::File::open(&path).unwrap();
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
let mut decoder = GzDecoder::new(&mut reader);

let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity((MP5_SIZE + 1) * 2);
decoder.read_to_end(&mut bytes).unwrap();
assert_eq!(bytes.len(), (MP5_SIZE + 1) * 2);

Exposing this Vec<u8> as u16s is a little more involved, but you can still do it in safe Rust with a crate like bytemuck. A Vec<u8>’s storage only has 1-byte alignment, so as you brought up in a comment, you would have to allocate an extra byte of space to guarantee correctness:
// note: with a suitable error type,
// this can return `Result` and use `?` instead of `unwrap`
fn read_table<T, const N: usize>(mut source: impl Read) -> &'static [T; N]
where
    T: bytemuck::AnyBitPattern,
{
    use std::mem;

    let align = mem::align_of::<[T; N]>();
    let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(
        mem::size_of::<[T; N]>()
        + (align - 1)
    );

    // ensure actual data is aligned
    let align_offset = bytes.as_ptr().align_offset(align);
    bytes.resize(align_offset, 0);

    source.read_to_end(&mut bytes).unwrap();

    bytemuck::cast_slice(&bytes.leak()[align_offset..]).try_into().unwrap()
}

lazy_static! {

pub static ref OJP_HIGH_MP5_TABLE_1: &'static [u16; MP5_SIZE + 1] = {
    let mut path: PathBuf = cargo_home().unwrap();
    path.push("onejoker");
    path.push("ojp_high_mp5_table_1.bin.gz");

    let file = fs::File::open(&path).unwrap();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let decoder = GzDecoder::new(&mut reader);

    read_table(decoder)
};

}

playground

Thanks. I'll give you the check even though I ended up doing it without bytemuck. I created it as a Vec first, then converted to , did the read_to_end(), and converted it back. That seems to work well.
